# Struts 2.3.24 throw deprecation warning

Tags: java, struts2

I updated a project from struts 2.3.4 to 2.3.24.

I'm facing the following warning (on each Struts action...):

```
[vitrine][2015-06-01 13:07:50,845-DEBUG] [http-bio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.debug(76) | 
*******************************************************************************
**                                                                           **
**                               WARNING                                     **
**                YOU USE DEPRECATED / UNKNOWN CONSTANTS                     **
**                                                                           **
**  -> struts.class.reloading.acceptClasses                                  **
**  -> actionPackages                                                        **
**  -> struts.class.reloading.watchList                                      **
**  -> struts.class.reloading.reloadConfig                                   **
*******************************************************************************
```

I think the struts guys are aware of the problem, but do somebody have maybe found something else to "hide" this log.

Comment: After some tries, I can say that the "problem" start on version 2.3.16 .

Comment: So don't use this interceptor OR set dev mode to false OR disable logging.

Comment: Yes Aleksandr I just realized it...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution was just to change the log4j level to error...